# Searching for Catch Throw in files (regex?)

Tags: regex, search, wildcard

I've got to fix up some exception handling code, where the base exception is not being passed as the inner exception

Ex:

```
Try
    SomeFunction()
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
        LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
    Else
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message) //<--- PROBLEM
End Try
```

As you can see, the original exception is not being carried on, and I need it to be.  I need to search across all the files in the solution and fix anything like the above example.  My question is how I can search for Catches with Throws in them?  That way I can just look and see whether the caught exception is being passed in.

EDIT:
For clarity, I need to find any blocks of text that match the general pattern:

```
Catch
    //bunch of crap
    Throw //anything
    //potentially more crap (should only be whitespace/newlines)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put it like this, you will get what you need

```
Try
    SomeFunction()
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
        LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
    Else
        Throw ex
End Try
```

?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to fix it, I just don't know how to FIND all the bad cases.  So I need to go look at every Catch with a Throw in it and make sure it's passing the original exception.

Comment: I'm missing something here: you're saying that in your code, sometimes the searched text is in the inner exception ?

Comment: Ok, I finally got it ! If it's VS, I think there is only one solution - CTRL + F

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/05/29/140147.aspx

I tried 'catch.*(.*\n)*?.*throw' in the Ctrl-F window (and selected Use Regular Expressions) and it found catches followed by throws..

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar situation to yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109055/2136840.

Adapting that solution, this worked for me in your case:

```
/(?<!End )Try(?:[^TE]+|T(?!hrow)|E(?!nd Try))*Throw.*?End Try/gs
```

Dissecting that regex you get:

```
(?<!End )Try   #find a Try not immediately preceded by an End

(?:[^TE]+|T(?!hrow)|E(?!nd Try))*   #take every character after that that isn't a T or E or is a T or E that isn't part of "Throw" or "End Try", respectively

Throw.*?End Try   #continue grabbing a Throw, any additional characters, and an End Try

gs   #global - match multiple, single-line (confusing name for having the dot match newline characters)
```

If it gets to the last part and there's no Throw before the End Try, it'll discard the whole block.

So putting it together in English, you have "find a Try not immediately preceded by an End; then take all subsequent characters until you get to a Throw and then an End Try in that order."

To test this out, I ran this in Perl:

```
my $str = <<EOS;
    Try
        SomeFunction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
            LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message) //<--- PROBLEM
    End Try

    'Other Code

    Try
        SomeFunction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
            LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message) //<--- PROBLEM
    End Try

    Try
        SomeFunction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
            LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        SomeFunction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
            LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
    End Try

    'Other Code

    Try
        SomeFunction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = somePreDefinedExceptionMessage Then
            LogErrorMsg(ex.Message)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message) //<--- PROBLEM
    End Try

EOS

while ($str =~ /(?<!End )Try(?:[^TE]+|T(?!hrow)|E(?!nd Try))*Throw.*?End Try/gs) {
    print "Next Error: " . $& . "\r\n\r\n";
}
```

Note: the syntax highlighting doesn't seem to like Perl's heredoc.

**Edit**: If you just want the catch block, use `Catch` instead of `(?<!End )Try`